# Listing the content of a tar file or a directory only down to some level

Tags: bash, tar, ls, depth

I wonder how to list the content of a tar file only down to some level?

I understand `tar tvf mytar.tar` will list all files, but sometimes I would like to only see directories down to some level.

Similarly, for the command `ls`, how do I control the level of subdirectories that will be displayed? By default, it will only show the direct subdirectories, but not go further.

Comment: Take a look at `tree` for listing multiple levels of subdirectories deep.

Comment: Seems like `tar -tvf mytar.tar | less` is a lot easier than most of these answers.

Comment: @Cameron does `tree` even support `.tar` files?

Comment: @brennebeck: I doubt it; I was referring to the part about `ls`. Sorry for the confusion, my comment is not very clear.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
tar tvf scripts.tar | awk -F/ '{if (NF<4) print }'


drwx------ glens/glens       0 2010-03-17 10:44 scripts/
-rwxr--r-- glens/www-data 1051 2009-07-27 10:42 scripts/my2cnf.pl
-rwxr--r-- glens/www-data  359 2009-08-14 00:01 scripts/pastebin.sh
-rwxr--r-- glens/www-data  566 2009-07-27 10:42 scripts/critic.pl
-rwxr-xr-x glens/glens     981 2009-12-16 09:39 scripts/wiki_sys.pl
-rwxr-xr-x glens/glens    3072 2009-07-28 10:25 scripts/blacklist_update.pl
-rwxr--r-- glens/www-data 18418 2009-07-27 10:42 scripts/sysinfo.pl
```

Make sure to note, that the number is 3+ however many levels you want, because of the / in the username/group.  If you just do

```
tar tf scripts.tar | awk -F/ '{if (NF<3) print }'

scripts/
scripts/my2cnf.pl
scripts/pastebin.sh
scripts/critic.pl
scripts/wiki_sys.pl
scripts/blacklist_update.pl
scripts/sysinfo.pl
```

it's only two more.

You could probably pipe the output of `ls -R` to this `awk` script, and have the same effect.

Comment: This is a brilliant answer. But I think you can simplify it a bit, since "print" is awk's default action: `tar tvf scripts.tar | awk -F/ 'NF<4'`

Answer (score 191):

depth=1

```
tar --exclude="*/*" -tf file.tar
```

depth=2

```
tar --exclude="*/*/*" -tf file.tar
```

Comment: But this can get only file name, not folder name

Comment: This answer is dope.

Comment: I used the depth=1 solution and got two different results on archives that were made by specifying the current directory as the target. On one I got no out put at all. The other gave the output `./` . I don't know why they were different.

Comment: I think this only works on GNU tar. On BSD tar (included in macOS) it only lists top level files and not directories. I think it has something to do with `*` being interpreted as 0 or more character and ends up excluding any entry with a `/`.

To include files and directories, I was able to use the pattern `"*/?*"`, and for depth=2, `"*/?*/?*"` would work.

Answer (score 10):

Another option is [archivemount](https://linux.die.net/man/1/archivemount). You mount it, and cd into it. Then you can do anything with it just as with other filesystem.

```
$ archivemount /path/to/files.tgz /path/to/mnt/folder
```

It seems faster than the tar method.

Answer (score 6):

It would be nice if we could tell the `find` command to look inside a tar file, but I doubt that is possible.

I quick and ugly (and not foolproof) way  would be to limit the number of directory separators, for example:

```
 $ tar tvf myfile.tar | grep -E '^[^/]*(/[^/]*){1,2}$'
```

The *2* tells to display not more than 2 slashes (in my case one is already generated by the user/group separator), and hence, to display files at depth at most one. You might want to try with different numbers in place of the 2.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with [leonbloy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700306/list-content-of-tar-file-or-a-directory-only-down-to-some-level/2700624#2700624) - there's no way to do this straightforwardly within the tarball itself.

Regarding the second part of your question, `ls` does not have a max depth option. You can recurse *everything* with `ls -R`, but that's often not very useful.

However you can do this with both `find` and `tree`. For example to list files and directories one level deep, you can do

```
find -maxdepth 2
```

or

```
tree -L 2
```

`tree` also has a `-d` option, which recursively lists directories, but not files, which I find much more useful than `-L`, in general.

Comment: True. And you can add the "-ls" option to the "find" command, if you want an output similar to that of the "tar tvf"

Answer (score 1):

I was able to show only the **directory** names at a particular depth using grep:

for depth `3`:

```sh
tar -tf mytar.tar | grep -Ex '([^/]+/){3}'
```

or for depth `$DEPTH`:

```sh
tar -tf mytar.tar | grep -Ex '([^/]+){$DEPTH}/'
```

You can speed that up by combining `grep` with `--exclude` from @sacapeao's [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8116375/623735).

for depth 3:

```sh
tar --exclude '*/*/*/*/*' -tf mytar.tar | grep -Ex '([^/]+/){3}'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ tar -tf mytar.tar | tree -L 2 --fromfile # 2 levels
```