# Is it possible to split a huge text file (based on number of lines) unpacking a .tar.gz archive if I cannot extract that file as whole?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command-line

I have a .tar.gz file. It contains **one** 20GB-sized text file with 20.5 million lines. I cannot extract this file as a whole and save to disk. I must do either one of the following options:

1. Specify a number of lines in each file - say, 1 million, - and get 21 files. This would be a preferred option.
2. Extract a part of that file based on line numbers, that is, say, from 1000001 to 2000001, to get a file with 1M lines. I will have to repeat this step 21 times with different parameters, which is very bad.

Is it possible at all?

This answer - [bash: extract only part of tar.gz archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24057301/bash-extract-only-part-of-tar-gz-archive) - describes a different problem.

Comment: do your file contain line number??

Comment: This might be a better question for [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract a file from `f.tar.gz` and split it into files, each with no more than 1 million lines, use:

```
tar Oxzf f.tar.gz | split -l1000000
```

The above will name the output files by the default method.  If you prefer the output files to be named prefix.nn where nn is a sequence number, then use:

```
tar Oxzf f.tar.gz |split -dl1000000 - prefix.
```

Under this approach:

- The original file is never written to disk.  `tar` reads from the `.tar.gz` file and *pipes* its contents to `split` which divides it up into pieces before writing the pieces to disk.
- The `.tar.gz` file is read only once.
- `split`, through its many options, has a great deal of flexibility.

#### Explanation

For the `tar` command:

- `O` tells `tar` to send the output to stdout.  This way we can pipe it to `split` without ever having to save the original file on disk.
- `x` tells `tar` to extract the file (as opposed to, say, creating an archive).
- `z` tells `tar` that the archive is in gzip format.  On modern tars, this is optional
- `f` tells `tar` to use, as input, the file name specified.

For the `split` command:

- `-l` tells `split` to split files limited by number of lines (as opposed to, say, bytes).
- `-d` tells `split` to use numeric suffixes for the output files.
- `-` tells `split` to get its input from stdin

Comment: Is this supposed to extract that 20GB-sized single file to disk at first? If yes, this is not an answer.

Comment: @lyricallywicked __No, it does not.__  `tar` reads from the `.tar.gz` file and _pipes_ its contents to `split`.  At no point is the whole file written to disk at once.

Comment: Thank you! So, I'm going to test all the answers. This may take about a day! And I'll accept or comment, later

Comment: Nice one.  I didn't know about `split` - this is like my answer but without writing any script at all!  Do you happen to know which Unix systems have `split`?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Thanks. There is also something new to discover in the Unix tool set.  As for which systems support `split`, since `split` is part of [GNU Coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#split-invocation), I expect that it will be on all varieties of Linux.  [Mac OSX](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/split.1.html) includes `split`.  Also, `split` is required by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/split.html#tag_20_120), so it will be likely found on other systems as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the --to-stdout (or -O) option in tar to send the output to stdout.
Then use sed to specify which set of lines you want.

```
#!/bin/bash
l=1
inc=1000000
p=1
while test $l -lt 21000000; do
  e=$(($l+$inc))
  tar -xfz --to-stdout myfile.tar.gz file-to-extract.txt |
      sed -n -e "$l,$e p" > part$p.txt
  l=$(($l+$inc))
  p=$(($p+1))
done
```

Comment: I don't know bash, but this looks interesting, I will test this. So, does that mean that 20GB-sized file won't be saved on disk?

Comment: It will be saved on disk, but in pieces.   You'll have to adjust the script to do some number of chunks at a time.  As is, the script will try to create all 21 pieces.

Comment: Right.  I made an assumption about not enough disk space, but rather you just have a problem saving as a whole.  I would use John1024's solution then.  Simpler.  My solution could be used if there actually wasn't enough disk space and you couldn't split the file into all the pieces at once.

Comment: The situation when I don't have enough disk space is also possible, and in this case I'll have to limit the output to one file containing no more than predefined number of lines, so this answer is useful, thanks again. By the way, you can check my next question: [My .gz/.zip file contains a huge text file; without saving that file unpacked to disk, how to extract its lines that match a regular expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27834818/my-gz-zip-file-contains-a-huge-text-file-without-saving-that-file-unpacked-to) because I'd like to see a pure Bash solution, if it's possible

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pure Bash solution for option #1, automatically splitting lines into multiple output files.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -eu

filenum=1
chunksize=1000000
ii=0
while read line
do
  if [ $ii -ge $chunksize ]
  then
    ii=0
    filenum=$(($filenum + 1))
    > out/file.$filenum
  fi

  echo $line >> out/file.$filenum
  ii=$(($ii + 1))
done
```

This will take any lines from stdin and create files like `out/file.1` with the first million lines, `out/file.2` with the second million lines, etc.  Then all you need is to feed the input to the above script, like this:

```
tar xfzO big.tar.gz | ./split.sh
```

This will never save any intermediate file on disk, or even in memory.  It is entirely a streaming solution.  It's somewhat wasteful of time, but very efficient in terms of space.  It's also very portable, and should work in shells other than Bash, and on ancient systems with little change.

Comment: How should this solution look if I don't want to use an external `split.sh` file and I just want to paste the complete code to command-line?

Comment: Then put the `tar` right before the `while`, like this: `tar xfzO big.tar.gz | while read line`.

Comment: please, check my next question: [My .gz/.zip file contains a huge text file; without saving that file unpacked to disk, how to extract its lines that match a regular expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27834818/my-gz-zip-file-contains-a-huge-text-file-without-saving-that-file-unpacked-to)

Answer (score -2):

you can use

```
sed -n 1,20p /Your/file/Path
```

Here you mention your first line number and the last line number
I mean to say this could look like

```
sed -n 1,20p /Your/file/Path >> file1
```

and use **start line number** and **end line number** in a **variable** and use it accordingly.

Comment: I don't understand. Is this supposed to extract a specific part of a .txt file from a .tar.gz archive? Where is the name of archive, the name of an internal file, the name of an output file an path to save the output? I didn't test this answer, but I think it won't work.

Comment: First you unzip yor tar.gz file in a patha and then you mention the unzip file name 'abc.txt' like `sed -n 1,20p /Your/file/Path/abc.txt >> file1`

Comment: I said I can't unzip an archive - this will extract that 20GB-sized file as a whole, I need to extract a specific part of an internal file

Comment: using `tar -xvf` you should be able to unzip any size archive file.

Comment: The problem is I cannot save 20GB-sized file to disk

Comment: This would be a great answer to a different question, but this doesn't answer the question as posed.