# My .gz/.zip file contains a huge text file; without saving that file unpacked to disk, how to extract its lines that match a regular expression?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command-line, awk

I have a **file.gz** (not a **.tar.gz**!) or **file.zip** file. It contains one file (20GB-sized text file with tens of millions of lines) named `1.txt`.

1. Without saving `1.txt` to disk as a whole (this requirement is the same as in [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27813237/is-it-possible-to-split-a-huge-text-file-based-on-number-of-lines-unpacking-a)), I want to extract all its lines that match some regular expression and don't match another regex.
2. The resulting `.txt` files must not exceed a predefined limit, say, one million lines.

That is, if there are 3.5M lines in `1.txt` that match those conditions, I want to get 4 output files: part1.txt, part2.txt, part3.txt, part4.txt (the latter will contain 500K lines), that's all.

I tried to make use of something like

```
gzip -c path/to/test/file.gz | grep -P --regexp='my regex' | split -l1000000
```

But the above code doesn't work. Maybe Bash can do it, as in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27813237/is-it-possible-to-split-a-huge-text-file-based-on-number-of-lines-unpacking-a), but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid It's imposible, quote from `gzip` man:

> If you wish to create a single archive file with multiple members so
>   that members can later be extracted independently, use an archiver
>   such as tar or zip.

**UPDATE:** After de edit, if the `gz` only contains one file , a one step tool like `awk` shoul be fine:

```
gzip -cd path/to/test/file.gz | awk 'BEGIN{global=1}/my regex/{count+=1;print $0 >"part"global".txt";if (count==1000000){count=0;global+=1}}'
```

`split` is also a good choice but you will have to rename files after it.

Comment: The problem can be with this solution that [tag:awk] use ERE and not [tag:perl] style regex. They have fairly different syntax, so most probably `my regex` will not work in [tag:awk] except for very basic patterns.

Comment: @TrueY Well, that's OK, awk regexes will be enough

Comment: @TrueY EREs are far from `vary basic patterns`. Maybe you're thinking of BREs as supported by default by sed.

Comment: @EdMorton: Sorry if I was not clear! I meant ERE (used by `awk` or `grep -E`) uses a very different syntax then [tag:perl]'s RE (also used by `grep -P`). But simple patterns can work on both (like: "my pattern"). Op specified `-P` in the Q, so I tired to emphasize that [tag:awk] can fail if [tag:perl] style RE is used.

Answer (score 3):

You can perhaps use [`zgrep`](http://man.cx/zgrep).

```
zgrep [ grep_options ] [ -e ] pattern filename.gz ...
```

NOTE: `zgrep` is a wrapper script (installed with `gzip` package), which essentially uses the same command internally as mentioned in other answers.
However, it looks more readable in the script & easier to write the command manually.

Comment: Oops! I forgot the good old `zgrep`! Thanks for reminding! Actually with `zgrep` you can spare some resources (at least one `fork` and `exec`).

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is almost good. The problem is that You should specify for `gzip` what to do. To decompress use -d. So try:

```
gzip -dc path/to/test/file.gz | grep -P --regexp='my regex' | split -l1000000
```

But with this you will have a bunch of files like xaa, xab, xac, ... I suggest to use the PREFIX and numeric suffixes features to create better output:

```
gzip -dc path/to/test/file.gz | grep -P --regexp='my regex' | split -dl1000000 - file
```

In this case the result files will look like: file01, file02, fil03 etc.

If You want to filter out some not matching [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) style regex, you can try something like this:

```
gzip -dc path/to/test/file.gz | grep -P 'my regex' | grep -vP 'other regex' | split -dl1000000 - file
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Does grep allow to filter lines matching the first regex **AND** not matching the second?

Comment: You can use `grep` and then `grep -v`.

Comment: @lyricallywicked Or even You can use look-ahead and look-behind buffers supported by [tag:perl] regex.

Comment: "You can use grep and then grep -v" - requires a significant amount of additional time, because you can't do something like `--regex="first"&&!"second"` in one single command, right?

Comment: "You can use look-ahead and look-behind buffers" - Some time ago, I tried to use regex-only way to filter something **NOT** containing something. All I remember is that was **too** slow. See [Regular expression to match string not containing a word?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word)

Comment: @lyricallywicked: Sure, using look-* buffers can be slow. That's why I suggested `grep -v`.