# bash seek file name inside tar ball

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Here I have test.tar.gz file, it's structure like:

```
folder/
folder/folder1
folder/folder1/aa
folder/folder1/bb
folder/folder2
folder/folder2/cc
```

Is there a way to find the name of first-level folder?

Comment: Which name in that output do you want to find? Also how large is the tarball?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For simple cases, what about:

```
tar tf archive.tar | head -1
```

---

... however `tar` archives are not necessary "single rooted":

```
sh$ mkdir -p folder/folder1
sh$ mkdir -p folder/folder2
sh$ touch folder/folder1/{aa,bb}
sh$ touch folder/folder2/cc
sh$ mkdir -p other/folder3
sh$ touch other/folder3/dd
sh$ mkdir -p yet/an/other
sh$ tar cvf f.tar folder other yet/an
folder/
folder/folder1/
folder/folder1/aa
folder/folder1/bb
folder/folder2/
folder/folder2/cc
other/
other/folder3/
other/folder3/dd
yet/an/
yet/an/other/
```

In addition, please note in the above example, the last entries: there is the *sub-folder* but not the root one.

In such case, you might extract the various "roots":

```
sh$ tar tf f.tar | sed -n '/^[^/]*\/$/p'
folder/
other/
```

If you need "unrooted" files too, this is more complicated:

```
sh$ $ tar tf f.tar | sed -n '/^.*\/$/p' | sort | cut -d '/' -f 1 | uniq
folder
other
yet
```

The `sort` is not strictly necessary in my example, but it helps if you have an *incremental archive*.

Comment: It should probably be pointed out that sorting this way means no output will be generated until the entire tar archive has been scanned.

Comment: @EtanReisner Very correct. This might be an issue for very long archives and/or on very constrained hardware.

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk`:

```
tar -tf bash-4.0.tar.gz | awk -F / 'NF > 1 && !a[$1]++ { print $1 FS }'
```

Output:

```
bash-4.0/
```

Comment: @SylvainLeroux I doubt that's possible. But for extremists they can have `awk -F / 'NF <= 2 && $2 == ""'`.

Comment: It is entirely possible. I was just testing that myself and was about to post that updated awk script.

Comment: Thanks for all the ideas. I just made a general answer to it instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Take a look [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700306/listing-the-content-of-a-tar-file-or-a-directory-only-down-to-some-level)

```
tar tvf scripts.tar | awk -F/ '{if (NF<4) print }'


drwx------ glens/glens       0 2010-03-17 10:44 scripts/
-rwxr--r-- glens/www-data 1051 2009-07-27 10:42 scripts/my2cnf.pl
-rwxr--r-- glens/www-data  359 2009-08-14 00:01 scripts/pastebin.sh
-rwxr--r-- glens/www-data  566 2009-07-27 10:42 scripts/critic.pl
-rwxr-xr-x glens/glens     981 2009-12-16 09:39 scripts/wiki_sys.pl
-rwxr-xr-x glens/glens    3072 2009-07-28 10:25 scripts/blacklist_update.pl
-rwxr--r-- glens/www-data 18418 2009-07-27 10:42 scripts/sysinfo.pl
```

Make sure to note, that the number is 3+ however many levels you want, because of the / in the username/group.  If you just do

```
tar tf scripts.tar | awk -F/ '{if (NF<3) print }'

scripts/
scripts/my2cnf.pl
scripts/pastebin.sh
scripts/critic.pl
scripts/wiki_sys.pl
scripts/blacklist_update.pl
scripts/sysinfo.pl
```

it's only two more.

Comment: Piping output of `ls` is indicative of bad practices in general; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs