# Fast list of top level directories in a tar

Tags: performance, list, tar

I have a tar file that is over 100gb in size, with thousands of files in, and I'm trying to find a way to list the top level but fast.

I've seen people [using --exclude and grep](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2700306) but this still has to go through all of the file names first, which in my case take a very long time.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I'm happy to be proved wrong, but I think you are out of luck. Tar files are essentially sequential *tape archives* which are not indexed at the start, as they can be appended to.

Comment: Ah, fair enough.  Is there a compression type you could recommend?  The problem is I have a lot of files, they are barely used, but from time to time I'll need to pull certain ones out.

Comment: Not a recommendation or endorsement, as I have never used it, but maybe worth a look... http://dar.linux.free.fr/doc/man/dar.html

Comment: That looks pretty cool, it has a catalogue structure to find the contents.  Sounds exactly like what I needed, thanks a lot!!  If you add it as an answer, ill accept it then.